# GZIP or deflate compression in IIS 8.5 with windows server 2012 r2 for ASP.net / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, compression, gzip, iis-8

We have a really weird issue, it seems that gzip/deflate is sort of working on our server. When running "YSLOW" to check if the page is compressed, it is on some workstations but not on others (same page).

I have added dynamic and static compression under IIS and have configured the web.config file with the following.

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

If it wasn't working at all I could probably troubleshoot the issue but the fact that it works on some workstations and not on others has me mind boggled. All workstations are using the same version of YSLOW and Chrome. The server is located in Austin, TX and when accessing from Houston I get no compression however when accessing from Austin or even India I did show compression, I then tried accessing from Portland with no compression. Has anyone experienced this?